# Given mean of $X$, estimate the mean of $f(X)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, means

The setup: Suppose that a random variable $X$ is measured $n$ times by conducting a physical experiment.  The experimenter finds the mean $\overline{X}$, then throws out all other data (and has no memory of what the distribution of $X$ might look like). Now, how can the mean of $T = f(X)$ be estimated using just this information?  Here, $f(X)$ is a nonlinear function, assume any other properties if needed like smoothness.

For example, say that
$$ T = \sqrt{\frac{7}{X}} $$
and its found that after conducting 50 experiments, $\overline{X} = 10$.  Based on this, what is the best estimate of $\overline{T}$?  It both feels like it should and shouldn't be
$$ \overline{T} = \sqrt{\frac{7}{10}}.
$$

My thoughts: first, this problem purposely isn't rigorous, the word "best" is up to your interpretation but should be reasonable.  The expectation of a nonlinear function isn't in general the nonlinear function of the expectation, $E[f(X)] \neq f(E[X])$ in general.  On the other hand, it feels intuitively correct that the average of $T$ would be $\sqrt{0.7}$.

Comment: Without any idea about the variance of $T$, say, no better guess seems possible ..

Comment: If one does retain information about the shape of the distribution for $X$ (not from the data but what you know about the process generating the data), then maybe determining the mean might not be a useful descriptor of the distribution of $T$.  For example, if the distribution of $X$ is symmetric, then you could consider $\sqrt{7/\bar{x}}$ as an estimate of the median of $T$.

Comment: You need $X >0$ as otherwise you run into problems with infinity or imaginary numbers. Then $E[\sqrt X] \le \sqrt{E[X]}$ but $E\left[\frac1X \right] \ge \frac{1}{E[X]}$ which is not helpful even to give a direction

Comment: ... but I think you will find $\sqrt{\frac{7}{E[X]}}$ is always an underestimate of  $E\left[\sqrt{\frac7X} \right]$ unless the distribution of $X$ is concentrated at a single value

Comment: Would it help if it was known that the sample standard deviation of X is $\sigma$?

Answer (score 1):

There is really nothing you can say without making additional assumptions. As a concrete example, let us assume that $X$ is sampled from a normal distribution with a known mean $0$ and an unknown variance, which we denote by $\sigma^2$. Take $f(x)=x^2$, so that $Ef(X)=\sigma^2$. We want to find some continuous function $F$ such that $F(\overline{X})\to \sigma^2$ as $n\to\infty$ (for definiteness, let us say the convergence should be in probability, although this is not so important for now). The crucial point is that $F$ cannot depend on $\sigma$, because $\sigma$ is not known to us; rather we must pick one $F$ that works for any $\sigma$.

However, $\overline{X}\to 0$ almost surely by the strong law of large numbers, so $F(\overline{X})\to F(0)$. Thus as we collect more and more data, the estimator will just converge to some constant value independent of the true value of $\sigma$.

Comment: Before accepting the answer, if you'd be so kind, could you give a list of assumptions that would allow us to say more about this problem?  References or anything would be greatly appreciated.